# MATLAB: Write Dynamic matrix to Excel

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm using MATLAB R2009a and following this example:

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-a-matlab-application-as-an-automation-client.html

I'd like to edit it so that I can write a matrix of unknown size into a column in an excel sheet, therefore not explicitly stating the range. I've attempted it this way:

```
%Put MATLAB data into the worksheet
Hop = [47; 53; 93; 10]; %Pretend I don't know what size this matrix is.
p = length(Hop);
p = strcat('A',num2str(p));
eActivesheetRange = e.Activesheet.get('Range','A1:p');
eActivesheetRange.Value = Hop;
```

However, this errors out. I've tried several variations of this to no avail. For example, using 'A:B' puts this array in columns A and B in excel and a NAN into every cell beyond my array. As I only want column A filled, using simple ('Range','A') errors out also.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having issues because you're trying to use your variable `p` in a string *directly*

```
range = 'A1:p';

    'A1:p'
```

This isn't going to work, you want to include the **value** of `p`. There are a number of ways you can do this.

In the code you have provided, you have already set `p = 'A10'` so if you wanted to append that to your range, you'd perform string concatenation

```
 p = 'A10';
 range = strcat('A1:', p);
```

I personally prefer to use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to place the number directly into my strings rather than concatenating a bunch of strings.

```
p = 10;
range = sprintf('A1:A%d', p)

    'A1:A10`
```

So if we adapt your code to use this we should get

```
range = sprintf('A1:A%d', numel(Hop));
eActivesheetRange = e.Activesheet.get('Range', range);
eActivesheetRange.Value = Hop;
```

Also just to be a little explicit, I would use [`numel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) rather than `length` as `length` is ambiguous. Also, I would flatten `Hop` into a column vector just to make sure that it's the proper dimension to be written to the spreadsheet.

```
eActivesheetRange.Value = Hop(:);
```

Comment: As you can probably guess, I'm quite new to MATLAB and your post gave me several helpful tips beyond just the question I asked.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the idea is to replace `xx` in `'B1:Bxx'` with the number of elements in your matrix.

I tried this:

```
e = actxserver('Excel.Application');
eWorkbook = e.Workbooks.Add;
e.Visible = 1;
eSheets = e.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;
eSheet1 = eSheets.get('Item',1);
eSheet1.Activate;
A = [1 2 3 4];
eActivesheetRange = e.Activesheet.get('Range','A1:A4');
eActivesheetRange.Value = A;
```

The above is directly from the link you shared. The reason why what you are trying to do is failing is that the `p` you pass into `e.Activesheet.get()` is a variable and not a string. To avoid this, try the following:

```
B = randi([0 10],10,1)
eActivesheetRange = e.Activesheet.get('Range',['B1:B' num2str(numel(B))]);
eActivesheetRange.Value = B;
```

Here, `num2str(numel(B))` will pass in a string, which is the number of elements in `B`. This is variable in the sense that it depends on the number of elements in `B`.